# Combine many related Git repositories into one repository with a commit history

Tags: git, github, repository, git-merge

So basically because of a university course I had to push repositories like this to my GitHub seperately because the professor preferred the oversight:

> /Assignment1
>
> /Assignment2
>
> /Assignment3

Etc.

These all have a folder with a project inside, and their own commit history.
What I'd like to do is combine these all into one repository like "course name assignments" and then have it be a repository with a root folder containing a folder each for what was previously its own repository.
Like:

> /CourseAssignments
>
> -/Assignment1
>
> -/Assignment2
>
> -/Assignment3

BUT also keep the commit history of the individual assignments.

Is there any way to do this using Git commands?

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories . Another option you may consider is using git submodules not doing a real "merge" but aggregating multiple repositories into a single "master" repository.

Comment: Look at this article: [How to merge two or multiple git repositories into one](https://medium.com/altcampus/how-to-merge-two-or-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-9f8a5209913f)